# How do I match 2 files and export to output?

Tags: awk, grep

I have 2 files...

1.txt

`quality@true.com:29d03982uj409382uj4e3nm432323209`

2.txt

`29d03982uj409382uj4e3nm432323209:false`

output.txt

`quality@true.com:false`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
join -t ":" -1 2 -2 1 1.txt 2.txt -o 1.1,2.2
```

Output:

```
quality@true.com:false
```

---

Take a look at `man join`.